# R print cutoff values under a certain value

Tags: r

I am trying to print only values over 1.1 for a factor analysis. I assumed the print command was what I wanted, but the cutoff didnt work.

Reproducible example:

```
print(c(1,2,3,.5),digits=2,cutoff=1.1,sort=T)
#returns: [1] 1.0 2.0 3.0 0.5
```

How can I get it to return only value over 1.1?

Comment: Try something like (assuming `num` is your vector) `num[num > 1.1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `print` function normally doesn't have `cutoff` - you are probably looking at a special implementation of `print` since it is generic, which means it can have different implementations for different data types ([see documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/print.html)).

To select elements with a criteria, you can do `num[{criteria}]`, in this case `num[num > 1.1]` as @DatamineR suggested.

Comment: Any suggestions for how to remove  values within a factor analysis object? I am happy to provide data if needed.

Comment: @Rilcon42: Could you try post more code? I'm not really sure what a factor analysis object is, do you mean the things here https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/factanal.html?

Comment: Yep thats it exactly!

Comment: Do you intend to extract values from uniqueness? If so `f$uniquenesses[f$uniquenesses > 1.1]` would work, for other attributes it should be along similar lines. You can post more code if that will help.

Answer (score 3):

This is three years too late, but the cutoff command does work in factor analysis:
some factor analysis where i only want loadings larger than 0.3:

```
print(factanal(df,factoramount)$loadings, cutoff=0.3)
```